# DensityPlot3D/RegionFunction of an Equation Instead of a Function

Tags: math, graph, wolfram-mathematica, density-plot, 4d

I am trying to model in Mathematica the concentration (density) of an intersection of two graphs, `eggs[x,y,z,t]` and `sperm[x,y,z,t]`. The issue arises when one tries to implement an equation describing the graph's boundaries `(sperm[x,y,z,t] == eggs[x,y,z,t])` into either `DensityPlot3D` or say the `RegionFunction -> Function[{x,y,z,t},func]` specifier. The methodology works for `ContourPlot3D`, however, `DensityPlot3D` is much more suitable for the task, as I am trying to animate the solutions and have the *color* of the graph be the concentration variable (4D output of sperm and egg equations).

Here is my code for the `ContourPlot3D` process:

```
In[1]:= sperm[x_,y_,z_,t_]= 1/Sqrt[4*Pi*t]*E^((-x^2-y^2-z^2)/(4*t));
eggs[x_,y_,z_,t_]=1/Sqrt[4*Pi*t]*E^((-(x+3)^2-(y+3)^2-(z+3)^2)/(4*t));
Animate[ContourPlot3D[sperm[x, y, z, t] == eggs[x, y, z, t], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, {z, -10, 10}], {t, 0, 10}]
```

The output normally crashes the system and thus cannot be uploaded here.

Here is my attempt to apply this method to the `DensityPlot3D`:

```
In[2]:= Animate[DensityPlot3D[sperm[x, y, z, t] == eggs[x, y, z, t], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, {z, -10, 10}], {t, 0, 10}]
```

The output is only a blank 3D plot.

After researching, I had found that `RegionFunction` (and `RegionPlot3D`) only seems to use inequalities, and the first argument in `DensityPlot3D` uses a function that is not in the form of an equation. I had tried to bypass this by doing something like

```
f = Solve[sperm[x, y, z, t] == eggs[x, y, z, t], {x, y, z, t}, Reals]
```

and inputting that variable as the first argument, but this did not help, as the result was still considered to be an equation (a complicated one at that).

So, my question is: **How can I implement the equation as a boundary for `DensityPlot3D`?**

EDIT: So it turns out the first argument can actually take in equations, as I was able to achieve an animation for `s[x, y, t] == e[x, y, t]`.

Here is the code:

```
In[1]:= s[x_, y_, t_] = 1/Sqrt[4*Pi*t]*E^((-(x + 0)^2 - (y + 0)^2)/(4*t));
e[x_, y_, t_] = 1/Sqrt[4*Pi*t]*E^((-(x + 3)^2 - (y + 3)^2)/(4*t)); 
Animate[DensityPlot[s[x, y, t] == e[x, y, t], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"], {t, 0, 10}]
```

I cannot figure out how to save the animation on here, and the picture is not uploading here.

Nevertheless, the problem then is simply the following: **Why is `DensityPlot3D` a blank graph for the "4D" case?**

Comment: for starters work the problem at a specific `t` before messing with `Animate`

Comment: @agentp Of course. Theoretically, one can animate any process given a manipulated variable, and in my case the problem exists with the actual interpretation of the first argument, _f_. So, my question applies to the "simplest" case with say `t = 2`: `DensityPlot3D[sperm[x, y, z, 2] == eggs[x y, z, 2], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10 ,10}, {z, -10 ,10}]`. I just used `Animate` to elucidate what exactly I am trying to do, as many a time responses don't answer the question, but rather produce the desired result with a different workaround *because* the questioner provided context of their goal. Apologies.